# Availability Group Integrity Check

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Please can someone point me in the right direction for doing an Availability Group integrity Check?

I have looked at Ola Hallengren notes on it in https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html

but I don't see a stored procedure for it under the 'Downloads' section.

Does any one have a script/stored procedure and the T-SQL command for me to use for executing the stored procedure for an Availability Group Integrity Check? Please note that this is not for an Availability Group Database Integrity Check.

Any hep will be appreciated please.

Thank you

Comment: What is an Availability Group Integrity Check? Do you mean a database consistency check for databases in an AG? Can you give an example of what it should do?

Comment: No it's not the availability group database. For example on this page https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html: 
We have a paragraph as follows:
 AvailabilityGroups
Select availability groups. The keyword ALL_AVAILABILITY_GROUPS is supported. The hyphen character (-) is used to exclude availability groups, and the percent character (%) is used for wildcard selection. All of these operations can be combined by using the comma (,).
…….

Comment: @PTL_SQL The first word on that webpage says "***Database**IntegrityCheck*". These are settings for Ola's scripts for managing database integrity checks against databases that are in Availability Groups.

Comment: @JD thank you for your comment. The source of my question was that, although my AG is now in a healthy state as shown on the SSMS dashboard, I however did see a past error in event log that says: "Always On: AG integrity check failed for AG 'AG1' with error 41044, severity 16, state 1" . So I was trying to get to the bottom of that error message and wondering if there was an AG Integrity Check that I could run

Comment: @SeanGallardy thanks again for your comments too and I should have given the source of my question as I've now done to JD and Peter. I guess I misunderstood the contents of the Ola.Hallengren page as has now been pointed out to me. Thank you all for your time and help. Much appreciated

Comment: 41044 is a symptom of a different issue, either with cluster nodes not receiving proper data updates from other nodes, someone/thing incorrectly manually changing things they shouldn't, other node connectivity issues, or 3rd party programs blocking/stopping/whatever access to the cluster database.

Comment: @SeanGallardy thanks for your comment. So I take it from all your comments that there is no such thing as an AG Integrity Check, rather what we have is an integrity check on the AG databases. As I said, I was trying to find the source of that past error in event viewer, just to add to my knowledge base. I thought it might have been produced by some script hence my looking for a script to do an AG integrity check. "Always On: **AG integrity check** failed for AG 'AG1' with error 41044, severity 16, state 1" .

Answer (score 1):

As also being said in the comments, this script does a **database integrity check**:

> SQL Server Integrity Check DatabaseIntegrityCheck is the SQL Server
> Maintenance Solution’s stored procedure for checking the integrity of
> databases. DatabaseIntegrityCheck is supported on SQL Server 2008, SQL
> Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, SQL
> Server 2017, SQL Server 2019, SQL Server 2022, Azure SQL Database, and
> Azure SQL Managed Instance.

The part of the Availability Groups will give you the possibility to only check the databases in a specific Availability Group. For example, when I give @AvailabilityGroups = 'AG1'. It will only do the checks for the databases in this specific availability group.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --// Select availability groups                                                                 //--
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IF @AvailabilityGroups IS NOT NULL AND @Version >= 11 AND SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') = 1
  BEGIN

    SET @AvailabilityGroups = REPLACE(@AvailabilityGroups, CHAR(10), '')
    SET @AvailabilityGroups = REPLACE(@AvailabilityGroups, CHAR(13), '')

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@StringDelimiter + ' ', @AvailabilityGroups) > 0 SET @AvailabilityGroups = REPLACE(@AvailabilityGroups, @StringDelimiter + ' ', @StringDelimiter)
    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ' + @StringDelimiter, @AvailabilityGroups) > 0 SET @AvailabilityGroups = REPLACE(@AvailabilityGroups, ' ' + @StringDelimiter, @StringDelimiter)

    SET @AvailabilityGroups = LTRIM(RTRIM(@AvailabilityGroups));

    WITH AvailabilityGroups1 (StartPosition, EndPosition, AvailabilityGroupItem) AS
    (
    SELECT 1 AS StartPosition,
           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@StringDelimiter, @AvailabilityGroups, 1), 0), LEN(@AvailabilityGroups) + 1) AS EndPosition,
           SUBSTRING(@AvailabilityGroups, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@StringDelimiter, @AvailabilityGroups, 1), 0), LEN(@AvailabilityGroups) + 1) - 1) AS AvailabilityGroupItem
    WHERE @AvailabilityGroups IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(EndPosition AS int) + 1 AS StartPosition,
           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@StringDelimiter, @AvailabilityGroups, EndPosition + 1), 0), LEN(@AvailabilityGroups) + 1) AS EndPosition,
           SUBSTRING(@AvailabilityGroups, EndPosition + 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@StringDelimiter, @AvailabilityGroups, EndPosition + 1), 0), LEN(@AvailabilityGroups) + 1) - EndPosition - 1) AS AvailabilityGroupItem
    FROM AvailabilityGroups1
    WHERE EndPosition < LEN(@AvailabilityGroups) + 1
    ),
    AvailabilityGroups2 (AvailabilityGroupItem, StartPosition, Selected) AS
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN AvailabilityGroupItem LIKE '-%' THEN RIGHT(AvailabilityGroupItem,LEN(AvailabilityGroupItem) - 1) ELSE AvailabilityGroupItem END AS AvailabilityGroupItem,
           StartPosition,
           CASE WHEN AvailabilityGroupItem LIKE '-%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Selected
    FROM AvailabilityGroups1
    ),
    AvailabilityGroups3 (AvailabilityGroupItem, StartPosition, Selected) AS
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN AvailabilityGroupItem = 'ALL_AVAILABILITY_GROUPS' THEN '%' ELSE AvailabilityGroupItem END AS AvailabilityGroupItem,
           StartPosition,
           Selected
    FROM AvailabilityGroups2
    ),
    AvailabilityGroups4 (AvailabilityGroupName, StartPosition, Selected) AS
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(AvailabilityGroupItem,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(AvailabilityGroupItem,1) = ']' THEN PARSENAME(AvailabilityGroupItem,1) ELSE AvailabilityGroupItem END AS AvailabilityGroupItem,
           StartPosition,
           Selected
    FROM AvailabilityGroups3
    )
    INSERT INTO @SelectedAvailabilityGroups (AvailabilityGroupName, StartPosition, Selected)
    SELECT AvailabilityGroupName, StartPosition, Selected
    FROM AvailabilityGroups4
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    UPDATE tmpAvailabilityGroups
    SET tmpAvailabilityGroups.Selected = SelectedAvailabilityGroups.Selected
    FROM @tmpAvailabilityGroups tmpAvailabilityGroups
    INNER JOIN @SelectedAvailabilityGroups SelectedAvailabilityGroups
    ON tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName LIKE REPLACE(SelectedAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName,'_','[_]')
    WHERE SelectedAvailabilityGroups.Selected = 1

    UPDATE tmpAvailabilityGroups
    SET tmpAvailabilityGroups.Selected = SelectedAvailabilityGroups.Selected
    FROM @tmpAvailabilityGroups tmpAvailabilityGroups
    INNER JOIN @SelectedAvailabilityGroups SelectedAvailabilityGroups
    ON tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName LIKE REPLACE(SelectedAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName,'_','[_]')
    WHERE SelectedAvailabilityGroups.Selected = 0

    UPDATE tmpAvailabilityGroups
    SET tmpAvailabilityGroups.StartPosition = SelectedAvailabilityGroups2.StartPosition
    FROM @tmpAvailabilityGroups tmpAvailabilityGroups
    INNER JOIN (SELECT tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName, MIN(SelectedAvailabilityGroups.StartPosition) AS StartPosition
                FROM @tmpAvailabilityGroups tmpAvailabilityGroups
                INNER JOIN @SelectedAvailabilityGroups SelectedAvailabilityGroups
                ON tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName LIKE REPLACE(SelectedAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName,'_','[_]')
                WHERE SelectedAvailabilityGroups.Selected = 1
                GROUP BY tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName) SelectedAvailabilityGroups2
    ON tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName = SelectedAvailabilityGroups2.AvailabilityGroupName

    UPDATE tmpDatabases
    SET tmpDatabases.StartPosition = tmpAvailabilityGroups.StartPosition,
        tmpDatabases.Selected = 1
    FROM @tmpDatabases tmpDatabases
    INNER JOIN @tmpDatabasesAvailabilityGroups tmpDatabasesAvailabilityGroups ON tmpDatabases.DatabaseName = tmpDatabasesAvailabilityGroups.DatabaseName
    INNER JOIN @tmpAvailabilityGroups tmpAvailabilityGroups ON tmpDatabasesAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName = tmpAvailabilityGroups.AvailabilityGroupName
    WHERE tmpAvailabilityGroups.Selected = 1

  END
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation and time. As I updated to JD above, the source of my question was that, although my AG is now in a healthy state as shown on the SSMS dashboard, I however did see a past error in event log that says: "Always On: AG integrity check failed for AG 'AG1' with error 41044, severity 16, state 1" . So I was trying to get to the bottom of that error message and wondering if there was an AG Integrity Check that I could run